# Alternative to Dirty Dozen jackpot SNGs?

Tags: online

I'm not sure if you know this one. iPoker network has had the dirty dozen jackpot sit and gos for ages, but yesterday they got removed from all sites. bet365 confirmed, that they wont get back soon.

Is there any similar alternative online?

It was a 12 people 2 tabled tournament with 1-4th places paid, 1K starting chips, 20BB and increasing, €2 in and €2000 jackpot for winning 4 in a row.

I guess it got removed because the jackpot was too easy to hit.

Comment: It sounds like you could easily game the system by having a bunch of shill friends enter and dump chips to the one real player.

Comment: I was constantly in the top 3, as entrants were simply amateurs. That's why I miss it :|